# Can I set Open Graph action not to use singular form ("a" / "an")?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say I have a "cook" action and "stuffed cookies" recipe.
When the action is posted, the following line appears on the timeline: "User cooked stuffed cookies on appname". On the news feed, the object type is being used: "User cooked **a** recipe on appname".

I would like that the first form of sentence will be used all the time (also in news feed / ticker), in order to avoid the singular form.

Is it possible? I've been reading and searching but can't find an answer.
Any other idea to avoid the "a"/ "an" of singular form (at all times) would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, the two basic ways it displays are:

`[user] [verb]  a [name of object type]`

or

`[user] [verb] [name of object instance]`

Either of those works fine for the example you provided:

'user cooked a recipe'
'user cookied stuffed cookies'